# What happens if, my image name and tag remains same? Will the deployment of the same image name and tag make any changes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, openshift

I have a pipeline which creates an image and pushes to Quay repository and then deploys to Openshift cluster. In my deployment-config file I have mentioned the image name as quay.:dev. So whenever a new image is created, it is created with same name and tag.
My question is will this pipeline and deployment make any changes to the pod running in the namespace or it will not identify any change and old pod will keep on running ?
Do I need to change tag on every run ?

Comment: Depends, if the pull policy is `always` it will pull latest on every start as the unchanging tag will keep overwriting the last one in repository. Otherwise it will re-use the one in local cache. General advise is that if you are on CICD server, use the build number as version suffix to image tag and the same in the deployment file.

Comment: I am working with Azure Devops server, I am not sure how the deployment file kept in Azure repos, would I identify the build number as version suffix.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the image tag on every run.  As a general rule, in Kubernetes you want to avoid fixed image tags like `...:dev` or `...:latest`.

With the workflow you suggest, two things will happen.

First, updating the Kubernetes Deployment will have no effect.  The new Deployment object will be byte-for-byte identical to the old one.  The cluster will see you want to have 3 Pods running the `quay...:dev` image, and those exist, so there's nothing to change.

Second, the images in the cluster can get out of sync.  Kubernetes (and plain Docker) will normally only pull an image if it doesn't exist on the node.  So if you do start a new Pod and some `quay...:dev` image already exists on the node, it will just get used as-is.  But say a node fails and is replaced, and it was running a replica of your application; the new node won't have a copy of your image, and if the replacement Pod is scheduled there then it will pull the then-current copy of the image, even though it's not the same actual build as in the rest of the cluster.

I'd recommend using a unique tag for every build of your application.  The source control commit ID or the current date/time are two things that are easy to use.  You then need to update the Deployment's `image:` on every build, but since this changes it will cause every existing Pod to be replaced with the newer image.

Comment: To be able to change the tag at every run, how would I ensure the dynamic tag creation ?
As in my deployment file what should I mention to have a unique tag at every run ? Also Is it important to do versioning of the images even for dev environment ?

Answer (score 0):

`My question is will this pipeline and deployment make any changes to the pod running in the namespace or it will not identify any change and old pod will keep on running ?`

If the field `imagePullPolicy: Always` is set, new image will be pulled despite they have same name/tag. This is because the [image digest](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-by-digest-immutable-identifier) has changed.

`Do I need to change tag on every run ?`

Highly recommended. Tag is a great help to identify which built is causing issue.

Comment: Same for dev environment ?

Comment: The described behavior applies to any environment.

Comment: I have added imagePullPolicy as Always, still the deployment config says unchanged. and no new deployment takes place.

Comment: Can you confirm the image digest on the host vs on the repo are the same.

Comment: Yes the image digest was same, the behavior is still unexpected, I have added build.id to the image tag and now a unique image gets created which triggers a new deployment

Comment: I am sorry I didn't checked the image digest properly, it was different the code was rebuilt and some files were added as well

Comment: `Yes the image digest was same...` -  In this case no pull will be performed as image on the host vs the repo is the same. If your pipeline built a new image and pushed to the repo, the image digest must have been different.

Comment: Also, kubernetes **DO NOT** watch your repo for new image. Typically, the pipeline which built and pushed the image should trigger the CD for deployment of new image.

Comment: The deploy stage runs within the pipeline, where a build and deploy stage occurs. Build- build a new image. Deploy- deployment of deployment Config with the image pull. This happens but the pod is not newly created. and keeps using the old image. 
as it has the same name and tag.

Comment: What is the command you used to perform the deploy?

Comment: oc apply -f <manifest-file>

Comment: Try: oc rollout restart deployment/<name>

Comment: I tried oc rollout latest yesterday, It triggered a new deployment of the pod.

Answer (score 0):

Hello when you say If the field imagePullPolicy: Always is set, new image will be pulled despite they have same name/tag. This is because the image digest has changed., I think, this doesn't work. I have it and my pod doesn't update with kubectl set image with the same image name tag :(

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33176573)